# How can we use fallen leaves from tree in best way?

Tags: waste, plants

In my neighborhood, there are so many trees along the road. So every day many leaves fall and everyday road-cleaning workers wastefully just burn it. I was hoping to use that waste in a more productive way. One idea I had was to dig it in somewhere for long time and it will become green fertilizers. I would like some other suggestions about how to use it. Please let me know to use this waste.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Composting (to enrich soil and provide fertilizer) and for use as mulching material (to reduce water use and keep weeds down) are actually *great* ways to reuse these materials — especially if you use them to *replace* less-sustainable alternatives (e.g. water soluble chemical fertilizers and commercially-farmed mulches).

Comment: yeah nice way to reuse

Answer (score 5):

You can use leaves in [vermicomposting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermicompost) as bedding and for extra layers between kitchen scraps.